# Is it possible to call an overloaded C# constructor from IronPython?

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to create a SessionState object using a TextReader.
https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/SessionSettings.cs

```
public SessionSettings(string file){
        }
public SessionSettings(TextReader conf)
        {
        }
```

I'm trying to call the second constructor. TextReader is an abstract class, and

```
>>> QuickFix.SessionSettings(System.IO.StringReader("BLAH"))
```

does not work, nor does:

```
>>> QuickFix.SessionSettings.Overloads[System.IO.TextReader](System.IO.StringReader("BLAH"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'type' object has no attribute 'Overloads'
```

I was able to call this by subclassing and implementing `__new__` and `__init__`, but is there a better way that doesn't require subclassing every multi-constructor type?

Comment: `TextReader` is an abstract class, not an interface. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx Not sure if that makes a difference though.

Comment: Having the constructors and call the way you show it should work. IronPython version? What error are you getting (in the first case)?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Suppose assembly A.dll references B.dll, and B.dll contains the target class to be subclassed.

```
clr.AddReferenceToFile("A.dll") # loads b.dll behind the scenes
clr.AddReferenceToFile("B.dll")
```

now the IronPython clr module implicitly has two references to B.dll, and this can cause absolutely cryptic errors such as the one above.

The solution seems to be to load only the minimal set of dlls, though I haven't seen much documentation on the exact mechanism of why this happens.

Comment: Are the two assemblies in the same folder? There's quite a lot of circumstances when you can inadvertently load multiple assemblies just because two assemblies are considered the same in c# only if they match on name, location, and version. So it would be (from a c# perspective) expected that loading `.\foo\foo.dll` and `.\bar\bar.dll` would also load `.\foo\bar.dll` if it existed.

Comment: Yes -- I should try to come up with a minimal example.  The problem occurred when naively trying to get started with IronPython, and loading all of the dlls in a folder.